# How to remove border in .FillRectangle garphics method in c#

Tags: pdfsharp

I am using following code to print graphics rectangle

```
var gr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(1);
 Color  color = System.Drawing.Color.White;             
 var brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(color);                 
gr.FillRectangle(brush, item.Position.X, item.Position.Y, item.Width, item.Height);
```

But when I execute above code there is border on that rectangle.That rectangle is in following image.

[image]

In this image border is showing when I execute above code, But is there any way so I can remove that border?

Comment: is that the border of the control? try setting `BorderStyle` property to `none`

Comment: `1` is not a valid parameter for `XGraphics.FromPdfPage()`. When people show code snippets then most of the time the problem is not with the code that was shown. Please provide an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @bansi there is any way so I can set BorderStyle  property to none?

Comment: XGraphics.FromPdfPage()- this is not my problem because it is working fine only problem is how to remove border.

Comment: `XGraphics.FromPdfPage()` is not your problem. Give us a complete project to replicate your problem if you want us to investigate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How does it look when you skip `FillRectangle`? I think the "border" is already there and your reactangle is just a little too small.

Comment: When I skip FillRectangle it will be only white(ie. background image color) And my Rectangle width and height is similar to my above reactangle showing in image.

Comment: Are `item.Position.X`and `Y` integers or are you off half a pixel or so?

Comment: item.Position.X and Y are float values

Comment: Can you try forcing them to integers?

Comment: Yes I have already tried it is not working.(means border is coming when i have change these values into integer)

Comment: Ok, assuming you're refering to PDFSharp's `XGraphics`, can you try using `DrawRectangle`?

Comment: Yes I have tried using DrawRectangle also but still it is showing border.